# Isomorphism from $T\rightarrow T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-space-isomorphism

I don't know how to do this problem. Please help me..

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$. Show that $T\rightarrow T^*$ is an isomorphism of $L(V,V)$ onto $L(V^*,V^*)$.

I have one more thing to clarify: Am I right in assuming $T^*$ as the transpose of $T$ and $V^*$as the Dual space of $V$ here?

Comment: $T^*$ is the dual operator of the operator $T$ which acts on the dual space $V^*$ as $T*(f(\cdot)) = f(T(\cdot))$. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $T$ can be represented by a matrix and $T^*$ will be represented by the adjoint matrix (which is, in the case of real vector spaces the transpose).

Comment: To add to Roland's excellent point: $T^{*}$ will be represented by the adjoint/transpose, but only *if you choose the dual basis to the one used in representing $T$*.

Comment: If the question is Exercise 7 of Section 3.7 in [_Linear Algebra_](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) by Hoffman and Kunze, replace $T^*$ by $T^t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V^{*}$ is surely the dual space. And $T^{*}$ is defined by 
$$
T^{*}: V^{*} \to V^{*} : f \mapsto  (v \mapsto f(T(v)))
$$
i.e.,  $T^{*}(f)$, for a typical covector $f$, is a new covector, whose value on a typical element $v \in V$ is simply $f(T(v))$.

Comment: @JohnHuges : I wanted an answer for the main problem as priority, a sub prior question was my little doubt.. I suggest you edit your answer to include the solution of the major problem.

Comment: Can you please explain what a covector is? I am a beginner, and not familiar with the term..

Comment: A "covector" is an element of the dual space (just as a vector is an element of $V$). Not everyone uses this terminology, but I find it helpful when discussing dual spaces. Similarly, I use $u, v, w$ for vectors, and $f, g, h$ for covectors, since a typical covector is a function $f : V \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: As for answering the main question: When you get a firm grip on the definition of $T^{*}$, you can ask [for your main transformation, $S$ from $L(V,V)$ to $L(V^{*}, V^{*}$], whether $S$ is injective and whether it's surjective. Is there a nonzero transformation $T$ with $S(T) = 0$? No...and a chase through the definitions will show that. I deliberately gave only the answer I wrote, figuring it would be enough to get you going and do the main problem.

Comment: Please show me how to show injectivity..

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dim V:= n=\dim V^*$(Since $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension)

Thus $\dim L(V,V)=\dim (V^*,V^*)=n^2.$

Hence if we show that the mapping $\zeta :  L(V,V)\to (V^*,V^*)$ where $\zeta(T)=T^t$ is $1:1,$ we are done.

But we have to verify that $\zeta$ indeed is a **function**(*trivial*) and a **linear transformation**.

- Let $c\in F,T_1\&T_2\in L(V,V).$ Then for a given $f\in V^*$ and any $\alpha\in V,$
  \begin{align}
  \big[(cT_1+T_2)^tf\big](\alpha)&=f\big[(cT_1+T_2)(\alpha)\big]\\
  &=f\big[cT_1(\alpha)+T_2(\alpha)\big]\\
  &=cf[T_1(\alpha)]+f[T_2(\alpha)]\\
  &=cT_1^tf(\alpha)+T_2^tf(\alpha).
  \end{align}

Thus $\zeta (cT_1+T_2)=(cT_1+T_2)^t=cT_1^t+T_2^t=c\zeta (T_1) +\zeta (T_2)$ so that $\zeta$ is linear.

- $\zeta$ is $1:1$

For any given $T\in L(V,V), T^t=0\iff T^t(f)=0$ for all $f\in V^*$ 
$\hspace{6.6cm}$i.e., $f[T(\alpha)]=0$ for all $f\in V^*,\alpha\in V$
$\hspace{6.5cm} \iff$ Range$(T)\subseteq \ker f$ for all $f\in V^*$
$\hspace{6.5cm} \iff$ Range$(T)\subseteq \bigcap_{f\in V^*} \ker f$
$\hspace{6.5cm} \iff$ Range$(T)=0$
$\hspace{6.5cm} \iff T=0$

Thus $\zeta (T)=0\iff T^t=0 \iff T=0$ so that $\zeta$ is $1:1$ and we have the desired result.